# exec-maven-plugin starts not in the right phase

Tags: maven, integration-testing, exec-maven-plugin

I want to start a server in pre-integration-phase and do some integration tests. Problem is that it only starts after the integration tests.

My pom looks like this:

```
plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executableDependency>
                            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                            <artifactId>MyServer-Server</artifactId>
                        </executableDependency>
                        <mainClass>mygroup.myServer.MyServer</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-batch</argument>
                            <argument>-port</argument>
                            <argument>1024</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and my Test is a jUnit-Case named `TestMyServerIT` located in src/test/main looks like this:

```
public class TestMyServerIT {

private Socket server;

@Test
public void testConnection() {
    try {
        server = new Socket("localhost", 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

which fails with a connection denied if try mvn verify.
But it succeeds when I have a server running.

If I comment the test out, there is a server running on port 1024 after "mvn verify" since I don't stop it yet in the pom file. And I can access it on this port just fine, just not in time for the tests.

How can I assert the server is started before my tests?

It seems I have another problem I need to solve first. Failsafe-plugin is not starting on verify and says it is missing its xml if I try failsafe:verify

Comment: I wouldn't catch any exception during a test neither unit- or integration tests. Furthermore have you checked the output files of maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: Yes it says java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
Or is there anything special I should look for?

Comment: Now I see that where surefire-data and I don't see failsafe-data. Maybe there's the problem.